# Pandas groupby three columns and split column

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I'm trying to group by three columns, and aggregate them so the columns (not rows) are split by the third group.

I am using the `groupby` method to get a dataframe that is split by the question, school, and gender:

```
df.groupby([question, 'SCHOOL', 'GENDER']).size().unstack()
```

[The table I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nefus.png)

However, instead of splitting the row by `SCHOOL`, I am trying to have `SCHOOL` as my column and split this with `GENDER`. SO I am looking to have `'Q3.1` as my index and `SCHOOL` as my column, but the `SCHOOL` column would be also split by `GENDER`.

Essentially the columns would the following:

```
(('Middle School', 'Female'),
 ('Middle School', 'Male'),
 ('High School', 'Female'),
 ('High School', 'Male'))
```

Comment: Is there a typo? Should question be 'question' ?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want `df.pivot_table(index=['q3'], columns=['school', 'gender'], values=['value'])`

This is the output i got

```
value
school  highschool  middleschool
gender  female  male    female  male
q3              
breakoff    15  1   16  2
excellent   17  3   18  4
fair    19  5   20  6
good    21  7   22  8
missing 23  9   24  10
poor    25  11  26  12
verygood    27  13  28  14
```

Here is the dataframe i used:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'gender': ['male']*14+['female']*14, 'school':['highschool','middleschool']*14,'q3': ['breakoff','breakoff'
,'excellent','excellent','fair','fair','good','good','missing','missing','poor','poor','verygood',
'verygood','breakoff','breakoff','excellent','excellent','fair','fair','good','good','missing','missing','poor','poor',
'verygood','verygood'], 'value': np.arange(1,29)})
```